# How do I listen to an event that's emitted bya ElementUI tree in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I use the [ElementUI Tree](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tree) via:

```
    <el-tree
            :data="data"
            :props="defaultProps">
    </el-tree>
```

According, to the documention a `node-click` event gets emitted when a node is clicked. How do I listen to that event and start a function whenever that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows:

**Template:**

```
<el-tree
 :data="data"
 :props="defaultProps"
 @node-click="handleNodeClick"
>
</el-tree>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
methods: {
  handleNodeClick(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

If you want to take a closer look at how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ncgoswjm/

Bye!